# DNS Lookup In SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, dns

I have a table with a list of IP Addresses in a column. I would like to be able to perform a DNS Lookup to return hostnames for each IP Address. For example, given 8.8.8.8, return 'google-public-dns-a.google.com'. I'm trying to write a function that utilises xp_cmdshell to call 'NSLOOKUP'. This is what I have so far..

```
create function dbo.dns_lookup 
(
    @ip varchar(16)
)
returns varchar(200)
as
begin
    declare @cmd nvarchar(200) = 'NSLOOKUP ' + @ip
    declare @tmp table (n varchar(max))

    insert @tmp 
    exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @cmd

    return(
        select ltrim(replace(n,'Name:',''))
        from @tmp
        where n like 'Name:%'
    )
end
```

My ideal use case would be something along the lines of...

```
select row_id, ip_address, dbo.dns_lookup(ip_address)
from my_table
```

Of course, I get an 'Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'INSERT EXEC' within a function.' error suggesting I can't really have an EXEC in a function. I thought I might be able to wrap the EXEC in an OPENQUERY, however, I wouldn't be able to supply the IP Address as a parameter.

Maybe I'm coming at this from the wrong angle, I'm sure there's a better way to achieve the same result. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: I've done something like this in the past using xp_cmdshell, but really I would suggest using SQL/CLR.

Answer (score 0):

**Really this is not the sort of thing you want to do in a function.**

Resolving a DNS name typically takes maybe ~50ms to ~4000ms but can take much longer. **For each address.** So regardless of how you do it, you really want to do it ahead of time if at all possible, and you want to keep the result to avoid doing it many times for the same address.

If you have a table with the IP addresses of interest, I would suggest creating a SQLAgent job whose job is to maintain a second table with up-to-date DNS results.

```
CREATE TABLE RdnsResults (
    ip varchar(16) primary key,
    datetime lastChecked,
    rdnsName varchar(500)
)
```

Your SQLAgent job will then check if there are any new rows (lastChecked is null) and updated them. It can also update old rows periodically.

If you really *really* need to get the result immediately, your xp_cmdshell should take the IP on the command line and ***put the result in the table***. Although your function cannot write to the table the `xp_cmdshell` command can. Your function can then read the result out of the table.

I should add that if you have any significant numbers of IP addresses you will need to resolve them in parallel, which for practical purposes, probably means writing something using in C# using Async.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I should have put in my original post that this is purely static data that will not have new rows added, it's a sort of one-off data warehouse arrangement. Having said that, I will begin looking into C# CLR and utilising parallelisation.

Comment: If it's purely static data with no new rows added, then **certainly** you want to use an external program (run by SQLAgent job) to maintain the data. Your function then just does "select" from the existing data. Such a function can be very quick if the table is indexed correctly. In addition, you can use the table in the normal way e.g. joins etc.